# Testing the independence of the experimental series from a certain parameter

Tags: independence, jmp

I have the following question. I have a number of experiments for different materials (see the picture in the attachment). The results of these experiments seem to be independent from material parameters, or put otherwise they obey the same trend and so far from each other.

[image]

How can I prove that the results are material independent? Or that the results of experiments are the same? What is the measure of these parameters?

If it's important to mention, I use JMP for analysis.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Regards,

Vitalii

Comment: I don't think you mean independent in the statistical sense. Also you can't prove that the curves are the same barring small random error.  But it may be that you can statistically compare the curves using functional dat analysis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fit a linear regression model with `material` and `bending angle` as factors and `c` as the response (under Analyze > Fit Model in JMP). Among other things, you'll get p-values representing the strength of the "independence" as I think you're using the term. It's not "proof", but conventionally p-values less than 0.05 are taken as strong evidence against such "independence".

[image]